# my UserProfile modelform rejects using user id to update and fill the form in the updateview class:

Tags: python, django

I feel stuck separating user model and userprofile model to generate two separate views and apps in general.
It worked for user but not for userprofile, I used userchangeform with user and forms.modelforms with UserProfile. I am trying to use updateview, so the user can see and update his info.
the codes:

```
#user profile models file

from django.db import models
from easyinstall import settings

class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to='uploads/profile_images', blank=True)
    bio = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)
    birth_date = models.DateField(null=True, blank=True)
    website = models.URLField(blank=True)

    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = 'users profiles'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

userprofile forms

```
from django import forms
from .models import UserProfile

class EditProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):

 class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('picture', 'bio', 'location', 'birth_date', 'website',)
```

userprofile views

```
from .models import UserProfile
from django.views.generic import UpdateView
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
from .forms import EditProfileForm

class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = UserProfile
    form_class = EditProfileForm
    template_name = 'profiles/profileupdate.html'
    success_urls = reverse_lazy('profiles')
    pk_url_kwarg = 'UserProfile_pk'
    context_object_name = 'UserProfile'
```

I really stuck with that "pk" thing, how to get the pk for the user profile and use it? is it ok to have id and user_id in the profile table?

kindly, review the template:

```
{% load socialaccount %}

<h1>Django Allauth Tutorial</h1>
{% if user.is_authenticated %}
<p>Welcome {{ user.username }} !!!</p>
<li><a href="{% url 'settings'  %}">change settings</a></li>
<li><a href="{% url 'profile_update' UserProfile_pk=user.pk %}">Edit Profile</a></li>
{% else %}
    {% csrf_token %}
    <ul>

        <li><a href="{% provider_login_url 'linkedin' %}">Sign Up</a></li>

    </ul>
{% endif %}
```

and the urls:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import UsersList, ProfileUpdateView


urlpatterns = [
    path('', UsersList.as_view(), name='profiles'),
    path('profile/(?P<UserProfile_pk>\d+)/edit/', ProfileUpdateView.as_view(), name='profile_update'),
]
```

I am using django 2.1, python3.

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to link to the edit view using the pk of the profile, not the user.

```
{% url 'profile_update' UserProfile_pk=user.userprofile.pk %}
```